# Letting IMAP server know that Alpine is fine with UTF-8

Tags: imap, unicode, utf-8, alpine-mail

I am using Alpine with a local IMAP server. For some messages, I get the following "advisory message" in Alpine:

```
               ***********************************************************
               * What follows is an advisory message.  After reading it  *
               * simply hit "Return" to continue your Alpine session.    *
               *                                                         *
               * To review this message later, press 'J' from the        *
               * MAIN MENU.                                              *
               ***********************************************************

   Alert received while accessing "{localhost:993/imap/notls/ssl/novalidate-cert/user="ca>

           Message 291 appears to be a Unicode message and your E-mail reader
           did not enable Unicode support. Please use an E-mail reader that
           supports IMAP with UTF-8 (see
           https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6855.html)
```

After dismissing this message, I can look at message 291, and see some non-ASCII characters in the `From:` field, in the `Subject:`, and in the mail body itself; my combination of Alpine and terminal program has no problem displaying those characters.

What do I need to set in Alpine to let the IMAP server know that it is perfectly capable of handling messages containing UTF-8 in header values, and to avoid this kind of advisory messages?

For what it's worth, the `Display Character Set` setting of Alpine in the setup menu is set to `UTF-8`.